# strrpos in PHP finding last character position instead?

Tags: php, string

```
$string = "01234567890*****12345678901234567890*";  
echo strrpos($string,'*****');
```

*why does this return 36 and not 15? ([click here](http://writecodeonline.com/php/) to test)*

> [from php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php)
>   **strrpos** — Find the position of the last occurrence of a substring
>   in a string

What am I missing out on???
Thank you!

**SOLUTION:**
using the answers bellow, I provided a PHP4 alternative

```
$haystack = "01234567890*****12345678901234567890*";  
$needle              = '*****';

$position = strlen($haystack) - strlen($needle) - strpos(strrev($haystack),strrev($needle));
echo $position; // 11
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably you're using PHP 4:

[from php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php)

**needle**:
If needle is not a string, it is converted to an integer and applied as the ordinal value of a character. The needle can only be a single character in PHP 4.

Answer (score 6):

WriteCodeOnline.com uses PHP 4.4.9 (test it with [`phpversion`](http://php.net/phpversion)) and [`strrpos`](http://php.net/strrpos) prior to 5.0 does only accept one character and not a string:

> The *needle* can only be a single character in PHP 4.

That’s why you code is handled like `strrpos($string,'*')`. In PHP 5.0 and later the returned value would be 11.

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = "01234567890*****12345678901234567890*";  
echo strrpos($string,'*****');
```

PHP Version 5.3.5 result is 11

if you want to get last occurrence try this

```
$string = "01234567890*****12345678901234567890*";  
echo strripos($string,'*');//36
```